# apply groupby over window in a continuous manner pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to apply groupby with a time window of `60 minutes` but it only collects the value in the hour it has appeared and does not show anything for a window where there is no value.

I want it in a way that for the window without any value it gives `0` so as to have the data in a more continuous fashion.

for example:

```
df = sc.parallelize(
  [Row(datetime='2015/01/01 03:00:36', value = 2.0),
   Row(datetime='2015/01/01 03:40:12', value = 3.0),
   Row(datetime='2015/01/01 05:25:30', value = 1.0)]).toDF()

df1 = df.select(sf.unix_timestamp(sf.column("datetime"), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').cast(TimestampType()).alias("timestamp"), sf.column("value"))

df1.groupBy(sf.window(sf.col("timestamp"), "60 minutes")).agg(sf.sum("value")).show(truncate = False)
```

the output i get is:

```
+------------------------------------------+----------+
|window                                    |sum(value)|
+------------------------------------------+----------+
|[2015-01-01 03:00:00, 2015-01-01 04:00:00]|5.0       |
|[2015-01-01 05:00:00, 2015-01-01 06:00:00]|1.0       |
+------------------------------------------+----------+
```

whereas, I would rather want the output to be:

```
+------------------------------------------+----------+
|window                                    |sum(value)|
+------------------------------------------+----------+
|[2015-01-01 03:00:00, 2015-01-01 04:00:00]|5.0       |
|[2015-01-01 04:00:00, 2015-01-01 05:00:00]|0.0       |
|[2015-01-01 05:00:00, 2015-01-01 06:00:00]|1.0       |
+------------------------------------------+----------+
```

**Edit:**

How do i then extend it to double groupby and equal number of windows for each "name":

```
df = sc.parallelize(
  [Row(name = 'ABC', datetime = '2015/01/01 03:00:36', value = 2.0),
   Row(name = 'ABC', datetime = '2015/01/01 03:40:12', value = 3.0),
   Row(name = 'ABC', datetime = '2015/01/01 05:25:30', value = 1.0),
   Row(name = 'XYZ', datetime = '2015/01/01 05:15:30', value = 2.0)]).toDF()

df1 = df.select('name', sf.unix_timestamp(sf.column("datetime"), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').cast(TimestampType()).alias("timestamp"), sf.column("value"))

df1.show(truncate = False)

>>>+----+-------------------+-----+
|name|timestamp          |value|
+----+-------------------+-----+
|ABC |2015-01-01 03:00:36|2.0  |
|ABC |2015-01-01 03:40:12|3.0  |
|ABC |2015-01-01 05:25:30|1.0  |
|XYZ |2015-01-01 05:15:30|2.0  |
+----+-------------------+-----+
```

and i want the result to be:

```
+----+------------------------------------------+----------+
|name|window                                    |sum(value)|
+----+------------------------------------------+----------+
|ABC |[2015-01-01 03:00:00, 2015-01-01 04:00:00]|5.0       |
|ABC |[2015-01-01 04:00:00, 2015-01-01 05:00:00]|0.0       |
|ABC |[2015-01-01 05:00:00, 2015-01-01 06:00:00]|1.0       |
|XYZ |[2015-01-01 03:00:00, 2015-01-01 04:00:00]|0.0       |
|XYZ |[2015-01-01 04:00:00, 2015-01-01 05:00:00]|0.0       |
|XYZ |[2015-01-01 05:00:00, 2015-01-01 06:00:00]|2.0       |
+----+------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the behavior of grouping by `window` as you have no corresponding rows between hours 4 and 5.

However, you can make it work by generating the intervals in a separate dataframe using `sequence` function and starting from `min(timestamp)` to `max(timestamp)` truncated to hours. Then, using `transfrom` function on the generated sequence to create structs of strat and end time of each bucket :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

buckets = df1.agg(
    sf.expr("""transform(
                sequence(date_trunc('hour', min(timestamp)), 
                         date_trunc('hour', max(timestamp)), 
                         interval 1 hour
                ),
                x -> struct(x as start, x + interval 1 hour as end)
              )
    """).alias("buckets")
).select(sf.explode("buckets").alias("window"))

buckets.show(truncate=False)
#+------------------------------------------+
#|window                                    |
#+------------------------------------------+
#|[2015-01-01 03:00:00, 2015-01-01 04:00:00]|
#|[2015-01-01 04:00:00, 2015-01-01 05:00:00]|
#|[2015-01-01 05:00:00, 2015-01-01 06:00:00]|
#+------------------------------------------+
```

Now, you join with the original dataframe and groupby `window` column to sum the `value` :

```
df2 = buckets.join(
    df1,
    (sf.col("timestamp") >= sf.col("window.start")) &
    (sf.col("timestamp") < sf.col("window.end")),
    "left"
).groupBy("window").agg(
    sf.sum(sf.coalesce(sf.col("value"), sf.lit(0))).alias("sum")
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
#+------------------------------------------+---+
#|window                                    |sum|
#+------------------------------------------+---+
#|[2015-01-01 04:00:00, 2015-01-01 05:00:00]|0.0|
#|[2015-01-01 03:00:00, 2015-01-01 04:00:00]|5.0|
#|[2015-01-01 05:00:00, 2015-01-01 06:00:00]|1.0|
#+------------------------------------------+---+
```

Comment: can you please check out the edited version and help me with extending your method to it?

Comment: Hi @RaheelAhsan, you can simply groupby `name` when you create `buckets` df : `buckets = df.groupBy("name").agg(...).select("name", explode...)` then add in the join condition `df1.name = df2.name` with `&` along with the other conditions.